# When I input a number value in cell, can it auto format to show all numbers I input after decimal point

Tags: google-sheets, formatting

So 132.468 & -186.0152 & 167.03... I don't want to have click format button every time to adjust it to see the whole number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format cells as **Format > Number > Automatic** to show all decimals by default.